# Are there Golang drivers for Postgres which support non-blocking queries?

Tags: postgresql, go, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand if Golang has Postgres drivers which support making non-blocking queries to Postgres server, like [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) in Nodejs or [Postgres r2dbc](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql) in Java. According to this [excellent](https://medium.com/avitotech/how-to-work-with-postgres-in-go-bad2dabd13e4) article these are the major Go client libraries for Postgres:

1. [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx)

> PostgreSQL driver and toolkit for Go. Today this tool is a better choice.

[Searching](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/search?q=async) for `async` in the repo/issues doesn't give any prospects of non-blocking APIs.

2. [lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) - a very popular library but not actively developed anymore. Searching for `async` in the repo/issues also doesn't give any prospects of non-blocking APIs.
3. [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq-async.html) written in C which supports non-blocking queries but I couldn't find any Go wrappers around it.

Am I missing any drivers? Seems that the current driver options in Goland are all blocking versions.

Comment: My application does a lot of requests to external APIs and reads/updates database often after such requests, so I don't want database to be the bottleneck in my app.

Comment: @hitchhiker Is `go` the keyword not async enough?

Comment: The app logic can't continue until database result is received/updated. Also connection pools are usually used with Postgres (over 100 is usually not good). So if I have 100 queries at the same time, the whole app blocks.

Comment: By making db queries async I can make more requests simultaneously (more than the amount of connections in the pool).

Comment: Asynchronous APIs do not provide any advantages over synchronous APIs when it comes to connection use. Are you asking for a driver with pipelining?

Comment: Go libraries typically do not offer async APIs, because concurrency is provided by the language. Rather than looking for a package which likely doesn’t exist, you would probably do better to describe the problem you are really having.

Comment: @CeriseLimón what do you mean when you say that async APIs don't provide any advantages? For example in Java world there're new [non-blocking drivers](https://r2dbc.io) which solve real problems even though Java language has a lot of options for concurrency from threads to future, that's because blocking database calls are a bottleneck for concurrent operations. That being said by the nature of the comments in the OP I guess Go doesn't have such drivers.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Also according to your logic even C-based libpq shouldn't have async API's which it does.

Comment: My claim is that an asynchronous API in Go does not have an advantage over a synchronous API in Go with regards to database connection use. I am not making a claim about APIs in Java, C or other languages,  I am not claiming that there are no advantages to an asynchronous API.   What is the actual problem that you are having?  Is it database connection use or something else?

Comment: I'm considering Go for a microservice and async db queries is an important factor in the decision. Example: make `N`  REST API requests and update each response in db. First `N` requests are made, then `X` responses get back (as the size of db pool) and are being updated in db at the same time (`N>X`). After another millisecond `N-X` responses get back but now the app needs to wait for the first `X` responses to be updated in db, only after some db connection is free can a new response be processed. With async driver `N` responses can be sent to db server at once. Does this make sense?

Comment: You don't need an asychronous driver to do this. Goroutines provide the concurrency you describe. Simply launch a goroutine for each sql.DB.Exec call.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand how goroutines can help in this scenario. I can create 1 million goroutines to perform 1 million db queries but if the size of my connection pool is 100 and db driver is blocking I will still be able to process only 100 queries at any given moment not 1 million.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what an asynchronous driver does. The postgres server can never execute more than one query at a time per connection, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Use connection pooling with Postgres i.e. multiple TCP connections are open to the program.

Use them throughout the program.

But async could not be achieved at network level here.

https://youtu.be/GTeCtIoV2Tw

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).